# Hashtable alternatives for better performance

Tags: java, android, arrays

I used Hashtable for pointing a set of indexes to a larger array, but it has not enough performance, maybe because I used a general hash class for a specific use. I remember there was a specific class in Android for mapping Integer to Integer and Lint recommended using it. But forgot that class name.
Anybody can help?

Comment: You 'remember' it from where? Not recommended in what context? Are you looking for `HashMap`?

Comment: @EJP Not HashMap it's still a hash which degrades performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean [SparseIntArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html)? The documentation says to use it as an alternative to `HashMap` when mapping `Integer` to `Integer`.

Comment: it could be better to say mapping **Integer** to **Object**

Answer (score 0):

The fastutil library provides many alternative Collection implementatiosn, check it [here](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/).

Answer (score 0):

All Hashtable methods are synchronized, like this one

```
public synchronized V put(K key, V value) {
   ...
```

if you don't need concurrent access use HashMap, otherwise ConcurrentHashMap which is tread-safe but lock-free

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayMap` is the new thing from API Level 19 (KitKat+):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/ArrayMap.html